# Probability of intersections of independent events with a twist

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I'm trying to solve this problem:

Let $(A_n)$ be a sequence of independent events.  Show that if $I$, $J$, are (finite/countable) disjoint sets, then

$$ {\mathbb P}{\Large[}~\bigcap_{i \in I}A_i \cap~ \bigcap_{i \in J}{A_i}^c{\Large]}  = \prod_{i \in I} \mathbb P [{A_i}]\prod_{i \in J} (1 - \mathbb P [{A_i}]) $$

I've tried to do it by induction on $|J|$ but to no avail.  Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: The events in the set $\{A_i | i \in I\} \cup \{ A_j^c | j \in J \}$ are independent. From this, the claim follows. Can you fill in the details?

Comment: No... I'm having a horrible mental block on this problem!

Comment: Maybe you should look up the definition of independent events. No kidding.  :-)

Comment: @jflipp The result is easy to prove for $I,J$ finite. How about them being countable, which rules out induction?

Answer (score 1):

If $A_i$ and $A_j$ are independent then $P(A_i\cap A_j)=P(A_i)P(A_j)$. For induction assume that this is true for $n$ events then $P(A_{n+1}\cap \bigcap_{k=0}^n A_k)=P(A_{n+1})\prod_{k=0}^nP(A_k)$. And Set up a base case and flesh this argument out.

You are just left to show the intersection of independent events has an independant complement. Then you can split the probabilities up over the intersections.

Comment: How about $I,J$ being countable? Induction does not help in that case.